# castError Mongoose, cast to ObjectId failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

```
app.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const Id = req.params.id
    console.log(Id)
    console.log('Success');

    const properties = await Property.findOne({ _id: Id})
    if (properties== null) res.redirect('/home');

    res.render('property-single.ejs', { properties: properties});
})
```

```
app.get('/search', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Search Success')
    
    try {
        const searchQuery = req.query.keyword
        const properties = await Property.find({ $or: [{name: {$regex: searchQuery, $options: 'i'}}, {desc: {$regex: searchQuery, $options: 'i'}}]})
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId(properties._id)
        
        res.render('property-grid.ejs', {properties: properties})
    } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    }
})
```

So when I erase the app.get('/:id) the bottom app.get('/search') is working fine, but when I added it back it return an error that says

```
const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "search" at path "_id" for model "Property"`
```

here is my schema

```
const propertySchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    jenis: String,
    lokasi: String,
    alamat: String,
    tipe: String,
    luas: Number,
    kt: Number,
    km: Number,
    carslot: Number,
    picture: String,
    desc: String,
})
```

Thanks before !

Comment: Can you log out `Id`? Also, why are you doing ` mongoose.Types.ObjectId(properties._id)`? `_id` in `/search` is already an ObjectId.

Comment: Define your '/search' route before/above the '/:id' route.

Comment: Right now your request to the search route is being intercepted by the '/:id' route thinking that the value of 'id' param is search.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I was told by my friend to do that... I will change it !

Comment: @NaveenChahar Woah It's working now ! Thank you so much sir ! I really have no idea the define order will affect it

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is happening because express registers its routes from the [top of the file to the bottom](https://gabrieleromanato.name/order-of-routes-when-using-parameters-in-expressjs). A good rule of thumb is to make your more "specific" routes at the top and lesser ones at the bottom.

In this case, you are getting the error because you think your route is hitting `/search` when really it's hitting `/:id`. If you swap the order of these routes in your file, things should work more predictably.